# Multiple start_urls in python/scrapy are running in order ? or simultaneously?

Tags: python, scrapy

Multiple start_urls in python/scrapy are running in order ? or simultaneously ?

I am expecting to download these 3 domains simultaneously but is this downloaded in order like
aaa.com --> bbb.com --> ccc.com ?

```
ex: start_urls = ['https://aaa.com', 'https://bbb.com', 'https://ccc.com']
```

If this is in order, is there any way to download simultaneously ?

Answer (score 1):

`Scrapy` is asynchronous in nature. It scrapes the urls in parallel and the order in which requests are enqueued for download is determined by the scheduler. Read more about how the scheduler works from the [docs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/master/topics/scheduler.html).

More specifically to your question, the urls are not scraped in order but randomly in parallel as determined by the scheduler. The responses might get returned in order but that is simply because they were enqueued in that order by the scheduler or they were returned in that order by the server you are scraping.